# Exception 'Call must be made on main thread' iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a react native project that gets push notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging. Have implemented methods for onNotification(), onNotificationOpened() and getInitialNotification(). While notifications are working correctly when app is in the foreground and forced closed, I am getting an error when opening the notification when app is in the background (not force closed). The error image is below. I have tried changing/ commenting the notification code, but the error is still present. I am quite new to React Native and not sure why is this particular issue happening. Any help in this regard would be really helpful.I have updated all pods related to firebase and cloud messaging. Below is also the react-native code. I have not done any coding in Xcode, so the Pod files is as is.

[image]

```
async createNotificationListeners() {
    this.notificationListener =  firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
        if (notification) {
            //const {title, body, data} = notification;
            //this.displayNotification(title, body, data);
        }
    });

    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notification)  =>  {
        const {data} = notification.notification;
        if (data.url !== undefined) {
            this.navigate2URL(data.url);
        }else {
            this.setState({url: 'test'});
            this.webRef.reload();

        }
        //this.displayNotification(title, body + data);
    });

   const notificationOpen = await  firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
        const {data} = notificationOpen.notification;
        if (data.url !== undefined) {
            this.setState({url: data.url});
        } else {
            this.setState({url: 'test'});
        }
        this.webRef.reload();
        //this.displayNotification(title, body);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some code...so we can help.

Comment: I had exact same issue.. using iOS 14 and react-native-firebase 5.5.6

Comment: is this issue solved? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 19):

Try this try-catch in ./node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/notifications/RNFirebaseNotifications.m

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(complete:(NSString*)handlerKey fetchResult:(UIBackgroundFetchResult)fetchResult) {
if (handlerKey != nil) {
    void (^fetchCompletionHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult) = fetchCompletionHandlers[handlerKey];
    if (fetchCompletionHandler != nil) {
        fetchCompletionHandlers[handlerKey] = nil;
        @try {
            fetchCompletionHandler(fetchResult);
        } 
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            NSLog(@"Exception fetchCompletionHandler: %@", e);
        };
    } else {
        void(^completionHandler)(void) = completionHandlers[handlerKey];
        if (completionHandler != nil) {
            completionHandlers[handlerKey] = nil;
            @try {
                completionHandler();
            }
            @catch (NSException * e) {
                NSLog(@"Exception completionHandler: %@", e);
            };

        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Use patch package as described here for rn firebase 5.X.X: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4610#issuecomment-755444001
Or better to upgrade rn firebase (recommended)